# Как и правильно ли совмещать ООП и паттерны?

Tags: веб-программирование, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Скажите пожалуйста, как и правильно ли совмещать принципы ООП и различные "крутые" фрэймворки, позволяющие создавать сайты с использованием паттернов MVC на подобии VUE.JS или Angular?

Comment: Одно другому не мешает

Comment: так у вас по-другому и не получится. При построении неких решений вы в итоге можете что-то унифицировать, выделать в отдельные сущности или логику и в итоге таким образом неосознанно переизобретёте существующие паттерны проектрования. захотите отделить логику от представления - изобретёте MVC, захотите сделать так, чтоб экземпляр объекта всегда был один - изобретете "синглтон", захотите один шаблон вкладывать в другой и это постоянно использовать - изобретете "шаблонный метод" и т.д. А уж без MVC сейчас мало что обходится.